# modifying a cloned element and reinserting in dom - jquery

Tags: jquery

```
    //dom    

    <div id='toBeCloned'><span>Some name</span></div>
    <div id='targetElm'></div>

    //js
        $(function () {
            //creating a clone
            var _clone = $('#toBeCloned').clone(true);
    // target element
            var _target = $('#targetElm');

    //now target element is to be filled with cloned element with data of span changed
            var _someData = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    //loop through data
            $.each(_someData, function (i, data) {
                var _newElm = {};
                $.extend(_newElm, _clone);//copy cloned to  new Elm
                _newElm.find('span').html(data); //edit content of span
                alert('p'); // alert added to show that append in next line inspite of adding new element to dom just updating the previous one
                _target.append(_newElm);//update target
            });
        });


expected Result:
1 2 3 4
resut iam getting is
4
```

Comment: i just created another question to simplify my question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452397/clonning-an-element-and-adding-it-to-dom-multiple-times-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just want to clone the element on each iteration. A DOM object is not a normal JS object (Well it is, but it has more to it which is why you have to use `createElement` in raw JS to create a new one):

```
$(function () {
    // element to be cloned
    var _clone_me = $('#toBeCloned');
    // target element
    var _target = $('#targetElm');

    //now target element is to be filled with cloned element with data of span changed
    var _someData = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    //loop through data
    $.each(_someData, function (i, data) {
        var _newElm = _clone_me.clone(true); // clone copy
        _newElm.find('span').html(data);  //edit content of span
        _target.append(_newElm); //update target
    });
});
```

Why your code failed, is though you were "extending" an empty object on each iteration, it was still always referring to the *same* DOM node. You kept changing its value, and appending it to `#target`. Additionally, the way `append` works actually moves the object, so you weren't getting duplicate objects.

Comment: i just created another question to simplify my question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452397/clonning-an-element-and-adding-it-to-dom-multiple-times-jquery

although your solution is somewhere near my requirement