# li element not rendering 10 times

Tags: jquery

I have declared an `li` element as global and tried to push the same in array. Later I appended the same in `ul` but only once `li` item got displayed instead of displaying it 10 times.

```
var items = [], ele = $("<li>brad</li>");
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    items.push(ele);
}
$("#myId").append(items);
```

But if the `li` element is declared within loop as below:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    ele = $("<li>brad</li>")
    items.push(ele);
}
```

It displayed `li` 10 times. I couldn't figure out the reason for that. Why?

Comment: you are moving the same reference to the same DOM node rather than generating new references to new DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the former method, you are creating a simple instance of dom object, which is added to the array 10 times... that is still a single dom instance only that is the reason it is not adding 10 times

A possible solution is to clone the element in the loop as it will create difference copies of `ele` instead of adding the same element

```
var items = [], ele = $("<li>brad</li>");
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    items.push(ele.clone());
}
$("#myId").append(items);
```

Comment: Will this be the best solution if i create li skeleton having multiple divs and anchor tags within li at the top and modify anchor & div in li within loop everytime and at the last append it to ul. Please suggest.

Comment: @BradWriedt if you have to modify the elements in the loop, your second approach will do

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you define a single `<li>` element, and you add *that single element* to the array 10 times. The first iteration, it has an affect, but the rest of the 9 times, it says "yeah, that's already in the array".

In the second example, you re-define a new element every iteration. It doesn't matter that you're giving it the same variable name every time... You are still creating something that represents a new object. And therefore, a new one is added to the array each time.

In other words...
Defining it outside the loop:

```
Create a new element
Add it to the list
Add it to the list
Add it to the list
...
```

Defining it inside the loop:

```
Create a new element
Add it to the list
Create a new element
Add it to the list
Create a new element
Add it to the list
...
```

Comment: Will this be the best solution if i create li skeleton having multiple divs and anchor tags within li at the top and modify anchor & div in li within loop everytime and at the last append it to ul. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the following, when you declare:

```
ele = $("<li>brad</li>");
```

outside the loop, you have a single instance of that object. What the jquery code translates to is something like, document.createElement("li") (and then creates a text node and adds that to the element)

However since you only created the node once, it can't get inserted multiple times. When you create it in the loop you are creating a unique instance each time, which inserts just fine.

There is some more information here: [Cloning an element and adding it to Dom multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452397/cloning-an-element-and-adding-it-to-dom-multiple-times) regarding the reasoning behind why you need to create a new element each time. If you really need to clone an object already created, use jquery's [Clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to create a DOM object ? Or do you simply want to inject markup into your menu ? The following works as you might expect:

```
var items = [], ele = "<li>brad</li>";

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    items.push(ele);
}

$("#myId").append(items);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5FVAj/1/

Comment: Will this be the best solution if i create li skeleton having multiple divs and anchor tags within li at the top and modify anchor & div in li within loop everytime and at the last append it to ul. Please suggest.